# Storing a function trait object in a struct does not live long enough

Tags: rust

I'm trying to store two functions in a struct like this:

```
struct Example<'a> {
    func1: &'a Fn(f64) -> f64,
    func2: &'a Fn(f64) -> f64,
}

impl<'a> Example<'a> {

    fn new(f1: &'a Fn(f64) -> f64, f2: &'a Fn(f64) -> f64) -> Example<'a> {
        Example {
            func1: f1,
            func2: f2,
        }
    }

    fn test_func(self, x: f64, y: f64) -> f64 {
        (self.func1)(x) + (self.func2)(y)
   }
}


fn main() {
    fn first(x: f64) -> f64 {
        x
    }
    fn second(x: f64) -> f64 {
        x
    }
    let test = Example::new(&first, &second);
    test.test_func(1.0, 2.0);
}
```

[Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=8c1c73b5a317d80c02ad2c581ebdcaed&version=stable&backtrace=0)

Generates the following errors:

```
borrowed value does not live long enough
    let test = Example::new(&first, &second);
                            ^~~~~
note: reference must be valid for the block suffix following statement 2 at 28:45...
    let test = Example::new(&first, &second);
    test.test_func(1.0, 2.0);
}
note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the statement at 28:4
    let test = Example::new(&first, &second);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
help: consider using a `let` binding to increase its lifetime
    let test = Example::new(&first, &second);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: borrowed value does not live long enough
    let test = Example::new(&first, &second);
                                    ^~~~~~
note: reference must be valid for the block suffix following statement 2 at 28:45...
    let test = Example::new(&first, &second);
    test.test_func(1.0, 2.0);
}
note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the statement at 28:4
    let test = Example::new(&first, &second);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
help: consider using a `let` binding to increase its lifetime
    let test = Example::new(&first, &second);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I'm confused as to how this is an issue of lifetimes, since both of the functions and the struct should share the same lifetime in main. Also confused as to why the compiler's suggestion seems to be identical to what I already have.

Answer (score 2):

Doing as the compiler suggests (*consider using a `let` binding to increase its lifetime*) allows the code to compile:

```
fn main() {
    fn first(x: f64) -> f64 {
        x
    }
    fn second(x: f64) -> f64 {
        x
    }

    let x = &first;
    let y = &second;
    let test = Example::new(x, y);

    println!("{}", test.test_func(1.0, 2.0));
}
```

As does

```
let x = first;
let y = second;
let test = Example::new(&x, &y);
```

I believe (but don't know how to prove) that the problem is that something has to be created to adapt the function pointer (`fn(f64) -> f64`) into a trait object  (`&Fn(f64) -> f64`). However, creating it in the `new` call means that it will immediately be dropped when the statement returns.

This is similar to the case of a literal reference, which has the same error:

```
struct Foo<'a>(&'a u8);

fn main() {
    let f = Foo(&4);
    println!("{}", f.0);
}
```